# Next.js Create-next-app does not download the next template

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So i try to create a simple template for next.js by running the create-next command. In  the picture below its stuck to that spot for hours doing nothing. What is the problem here?

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to use `NPX` instead of `YARN` to create a next app? I never faced any problem with that.

```
npx create-next-app
```

If for some reason the command above didn't work try following command

```
npx create-next-app my-app --use-npm
```